# Run a macro automatically the first time that workbook is opened each day

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet to monitor insurance cover for subcontractors.

When the expiry date listed in one of the columns has passed (i.e. their insurance is out of date), the cell with the renewal date turns from green to red and in turn, an adjacent cell turns from True to False. This change of True to False triggers code that sends an email to remind me that the insurance has expired.

The macro runs every time this workbook opens. As this sheet is opened and closed multiple times per day, I'd like to make it run **only** when it is opened for the first time each day.
Several people will be CC'd to the email and I'd like to avoid pinging them multiple times with the same email.

**Code that triggers the email. It is in the "Sheet 1" window.**

```vb
Dim xRg As Range
'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("H3:H7,L3:L7,P3:P7, U3:U7"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = False Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub


Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Transport, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Our records indicate a sub-contractor's cover has expired." & vbNewLine & _
              "- @Transport: Please check the Sub-Contractor Cover spreadsheet to determine the correct sub-contractor," & vbNewLine & _
              "- @Operations: please suspend the relevant sub-contractor until they supply a copy of their updated cover." & vbNewLine & _
              vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
               "Best regards," & vbNewLine & _
               "Sub-Contractor Notification Service"
               
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "Me@WorkAddress.co.uk"
        .CC = "Operations@WorkAddress.co.uk; OperationsManager@WOrkAddress.co.uk"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "(Test) URGENT: A Sub-Contractor's Cover Has Expired"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Code that triggers the macro to run on opening the workbook. It is in the "This workbook" window.**

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_open()
    Sheet1.Mail_small_Text_Outlook
End Sub
```

Comment: Store a date in a cell on a worksheet (or in a workbook Name) - if that date isn't today's date then run `Mail_small_Text_Outlook` and update the stored date to today's date.

Comment: You can also try `customdocumentproperties`.